# Directory made with php cannot be manually opened

Tags: php, directory

I am using the iOS draft code php app.
I have written some code that should make a file or directory.
The code works fine for creating files but when a folder is made it shows up but I cannot manually open it.
Relative code:

```
($folder?mkdir($path, 0755, true) : fopen($path, 'w')) or die('Cannot create file:  '.$path);
```

`$path` is a string with the path the file will be created and `$folder` is a Boolean.
What's wrong?

Comment: you cannot use `fopen` to create the folders. use `mkdir` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: Go to the directory just before the final one in $path, and do ls -alp.  With this you will see if the permissions were assigned ok.  Based on 755, all users should be able to cd into the directory, so check that first.

Comment: I ran fileperms(); and got 33188

Answer (score 1):

You are  using fopen  that is for files not for dirs try [readdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php):

```
($folder?mkdir($path, 0755, true) : readdir($path, 'w')) or die('Cannot create file:  '.$path);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others and the documentation state, `fopen()` opens a file. To read directory contents, use `readdir()`: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

Comment: "As others and the documentation state" - then why add as an answer? You just restated Álvaro Touzón's earlier answer (but without example code, and a different URL to the same php.net function documentation).

Comment: Álvaro Touzón's answer was not yet posted when I posted mine.

Comment: Apologies, when I checked it showed his answer posted 2 hours ago but yours only an hour ago.

Comment: No problem, I +1'd Alvaro's answer, since mine was "based" on his comment.

Comment: I'm not trying to read the php, I'm trying to make the folder with php and open it afterwards manually.

Comment: Read the directory with php I mean

Comment: I might be confused, what do you mean "open it manually"? Open it in Finder/Windows Explorer??

Comment: I'm on iOS but basically yes